# Two definitions of super-Virasoro algebra

Tags: supersymmetry, lie-superalgebras, virasoro-algebra

Let $A=\mathbb C[x,\epsilon]$ where $x$ is an even variable and $\epsilon$ is an odd variable (thus $A$ is a commutative super-algebra). Let $\mathfrak g$ denote the Lie super-algebra of vector fields (i.e. differentiations) on $A$.

On the other hand, let $B=\mathbb C[x,\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2]$ where $x$ is even and $\epsilon_i$ are odd. Let $\theta_i=\epsilon_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon_i}$. Let $\mathfrak g'$ be the Lie super-algebra of vector fields on $B$ preserving the odd distribution $L$ spanned by $\theta_1,\theta_2$.

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Is it true that $\mathfrak g$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak g'$? What is the reference to this result? Does it have a simple proof?